# Autofac not hitting constructor with parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, autofac

Autofac's default is to use the constructor with the most parameters yet it keeps hitting the parameterless default constructor.

Consuming class:

```
using AlbumApp.Core.Common.Contracts;
using AlbumApp.Core.Common.UI.Core;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AlbumApp.Admin.ViewModels
{
  public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
  {
    private static IServiceFactory _serviceFactory;

    public MainViewModel() { }

    public MainViewModel(IServiceFactory serviceFactory)
    { _serviceFactory = serviceFactory; }

    private DashboardViewModel _dashboardViewModel = new DashboardViewModel(_serviceFactory);

    public DashboardViewModel DashboardViewModel { get { return _dashboardViewModel; } private set { } } // = new DashboardViewModel();
  }
}
```

AutofacLoader:

```
using AlbumApp.Client.Proxies;
using AlbumApp.Core.Common.Contracts;
using Autofac;
using System.Reflection;

namespace AlbumApp.Admin.Bootstrapper
{
  public static class AutoFacLoader
  {
    public static IContainer Init() { 
      var builder = Builder();
      return builder.Build(); }

    public static ContainerBuilder Builder() {
      var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
      builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
        .InNamespace("AlbumApp.Admin.ViewModels").SingleInstance();
      builder.RegisterType<ServiceFactory>().As<IServiceFactory>();

      return builder; }
  }
}
```

App.xaml.cs

```
using AlbumApp.Admin.Bootstrapper;
using AlbumApp.Core.Common.Core;
using System.Windows;

namespace AlbumApp.Admin
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class App : Application
  {
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
      base.OnStartup(e);

      ObjectBase.Container = AutoFacLoader.Init();

    }
  }
}
```

When I set a `breakpoint` on the `builder.Build` and check the `ComponentRegistry` it contains the `ServiceFactory`.

`{Activator = ServiceFactory (ReflectionActivator), Services = [AlbumApp.Core.Common.Contracts.IServiceFactory], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope}`

I also set a breakpoint on the two constructors of the `MainViewModel` and only the default constructor is hit so the `_serviceFactory` is null.

How do I get Autofac to inject a `ServiceFactory`?

Call Stack on parameterless constructor:

> AlbumApp.Admin.exe!AlbumApp.Admin.ViewModels.MainViewModel.MainViewModel() Line 15  C#
>       AlbumApp.Admin.exe!AlbumApp.Admin.MainWindow.MainWindow() Line 30   C#
>       [Native to Managed Transition]
>       [Managed to Native Transition]
>       mscorlib.dll!System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(bool publicOnly, bool skipCheckThis, bool fillCache, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark)  Unknown
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type type, bool nonPublic)  Unknown
>       mscorlib.dll!System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object[] activationAttributes, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark)  Unknown
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type type, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object[] activationAttributes) Unknown
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type type, object[] args)   Unknown
>       System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.Schema.SafeReflectionInvoker.CreateInstanceCritical(System.Type type, object[] arguments)   Unknown
>       System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.Schema.SafeReflectionInvoker.CreateInstance(System.Type type, object[] arguments)   Unknown
>       System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.Schema.XamlTypeInvoker.CreateInstanceWithActivator(System.Type type, object[] arguments)    Unknown
>       System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.Schema.XamlTypeInvoker.CreateInstance(object[] arguments)   Unknown
>       System.Xaml.dll!MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CreateInstanceWithCtor(System.Xaml.XamlType xamlType, object[] args)  Unknown
>       System.Xaml.dll!MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CreateInstance(System.Xaml.XamlType xamlType, object[] args)  Unknown
>       System.Xaml.dll!MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.PartialTrustTolerantRuntime.CreateInstance(System.Xaml.XamlType xamlType, object[] args)   Unknown
>       System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_CreateAndAssignToParentStart(MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.ObjectWriterContext ctx)   Unknown
>       System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteStartMember(System.Xaml.XamlMember property)  Unknown
>       System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlWriter.WriteNode(System.Xaml.XamlReader reader) Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.TransformNodes(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter xamlWriter, bool onlyLoadOneNode, bool skipJournaledProperties, bool shouldPassLineNumberInfo, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfo xamlLineInfo, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfoConsumer xamlLineInfoConsumer, MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.XamlContextStack stack, System.Windows.Markup.IStyleConnector styleConnector)  Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, bool skipJournaledProperties, object rootObject, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, System.Uri baseUri)   Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, bool skipJournaledProperties, object rootObject, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, System.Uri baseUri) Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext parserContext, object parent, bool closeStream)    Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(System.IO.Stream stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext pc)    Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Uri resourceLocator, bool bSkipJournaledProperties)   Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()    Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application..ctor.AnonymousMethod__1_0(object unused)  Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs)  Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()   Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(object state)  Unknown
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state)  Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()   Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()  Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)  Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object o) Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs)  Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs)   Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.Delegate method, object arg)    Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam)  Unknown
>       [Native to Managed Transition]
>       [Managed to Native Transition]
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.TranslateAndDispatchMessage(ref System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg) Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame)   Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame)   Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()   Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(object ignore)   Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window window)  Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window window)  Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run()  Unknown
>       AlbumApp.Admin.exe!AlbumApp.Admin.App.Main()    Unknown
>       [Native to Managed Transition]
>       [Managed to Native Transition]
>       mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly assembly, string[] args)   Unknown
>       mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(string assemblyFile, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, string[] args) Unknown
>       Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()   Unknown
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state)    Unknown
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Unknown
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()    Unknown

Comment: Could you add a breakpoint on the constructor and post the stack trace ? The type may not be initialized by Autofac.

Comment: What stack trace?  There is no error thrown so there is no stack trace.  It never hits the constructor with the `IServiceFactory serviceFactory` parameter.

Comment: I meant call stack when the parameterless constructor is hitted.

Comment: It' been posted.

Comment: Your class is not constructed by Autofac but by WPF. How do you link your `AutoFacLoader` to your WPF application ? I don't know enough about WPF but the problem seems to be there.

Comment: I call the `AutoFacLoader.Init` from the `OnStartUp` in the `App.xaml.cs`.  I added the `App.xaml.cs` to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ViewModelBase` class contains the `AutoFac` `Container` which gets populated in the `App.xaml.cs`. Initialize the `ViewModels` by resolving them from the `Container`.

Updated MainViewModel.cs

```
  public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
  {
    public MainViewModel() { } 

    public DashboardViewModel DashboardViewModel {
      get { return Container.Resolve<DashboardViewModel>(); }    private set { } }

    public MaintainAlbumsViewModel MaintainAlbumsViewModel {
      get { return Container.Resolve<MaintainAlbumsViewModel>(); }     private set { } }

    public OrdersViewModel OrdersViewModel {
      get { return Container.Resolve<OrdersViewModel>(); }       private set { }
    }
  }
```